# locationManager:didExitRegion: not called when screen is off

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-location, geofencing

I am using region monitoring to run some code when the user exits a region. When the app is running in the foreground or in the background with the device's screen on `locationManger:didExitRegion:` is called as expected. However, when the screen is off I usually don't get the callback until I turn the screen on, by clicking the power button, at which point `locationManger:didExitRegion:` is called immediately. All of the testing was done on an iPhone 5s.

Here's how I set the region:

```
self.monitoredRegion = [self setupGeoFenceWithCenter:self.currentLocation radius:200];
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.monitoredRegion];

-(CLRegion *)setupGeoFenceWithCenter:(CLLocation *)center radius:(CGFloat)radius
{
    if (radius > self.locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance)
    {
        radius = self.locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance;
    } 
    CLRegion * region =  [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:center.coordinate
                                                           radius:radius
                                                       identifier:@"geofence"];
    return region;
}
```

Here's the delegate callback:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Exited Region");
}
```

Here's the `CLLocationManager` initialisation:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
```

Also, lately I've noticed that the `locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError:` method is getting called more often with the following error description:

> Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 5.)"

but even with this error, when the app is in the foreground it works as expected.
Is this the expected behaviour for region monitoring? Has anyone else encountered this? Could this be a result of the error I'm getting?

Thanks!

Comment: I am testing it with iOS simulator's Freeway drive simulation. My delegates are never called.. any idea? I have set up the delegates and CLLocationManager object is also retained...

Answer (score -1):

Did you try waiting several minutes (4 to 15) ? PS : your app should be in foreground before switch your iDevice off. This is based on iBeacon tests... hop it can help in your case.

Comment: 4-15 minutes seems excessive. Is it written in the documentation? Also, why do you say the app has to be in the foreground? According to Apple even the app is terminated, once a region boundary is crossed the app is launched and gets the notification.